# ngModel Acting Strange - Angular2

Tags: html, angular, typescript

```
myList: any;
ngOnInit(){
    this.myList = [
        {id: 1, name: 'a'},
        {id: 2, name: 'b'},
        {id: 3, name: 'c'},
        {id: 4, name: 'd'},
    ];
}
```

In my html

```
<input *ngFor="let l of myList" [(ngModel)]="l.name" name="{{l.id}}" />
```

It's working good as below:

[image]

Chrome Dev:

[image]

Then when I call another service in my ngOnInit like below:

```
myList: any;
ngOnInit(){
    this.myList = [
        {id: 1, name: 'a'},
        {id: 2, name: 'b'},
        {id: 3, name: 'c'},
        {id: 4, name: 'd'},
    ];

    this.outletService.getAll().then(outlets => {
         this.outlets = outlets;
    });
}
```

Suddenly, there is no value in the input as you see below: My html code is the same.

[image]

[image]

What could possibly be happened? How can I get the value to appear in the inputs?

Here is the outletService .getAll()

```
getAll() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        let headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        this.http.get(this.host + '/outlets', options)
            .subscribe(data => {
                resolve(data.json()); //Return array of objects
            });
    });
}
```

Here is the return from the outletService:

[image]

There is no error in the console, and I want the property `name` from `this.myList`, not `outletName` from `this.outlets`.

[image]

### Update

What's more interesting is: I don't even need to call another service:
If i just assign new array to this.outlets, it won't work, like this case:

```
myList: any;
outlets: any;
ngOnInit(){
    this.myList = [
        {id: 1, name: 'a'},
        {id: 2, name: 'b'},
        {id: 3, name: 'c'},
        {id: 4, name: 'd'},
    ];
    this.outlets = [
        {id: 1, name: 'a'},
        {id: 2, name: 'b'},
        {id: 3, name: 'c'},
        {id: 4, name: 'd'},
    ];
}
```

And add another line to the html file.

```
<input *ngFor="let l of myList" [(ngModel)]="l.name" name="{{l.id}}" />
<input *ngFor="let o of outlets" [(ngModel)]="o.outletName" name="{{o.id}}" />
```

Comment: What does `outletService.getAll()` return?

Comment: it returns Object Array.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: no errors in console

Comment: How does the object array look like exactly?

Comment: I've updated in the question, is it that one?

Comment: The expanded item doesn't seem to have a `name` property. Have you checked the errors in the console already (as mentioned by @garethb)?

Comment: But I want the Input from this.myList, not this.outlets.

Comment: I've updated the console to show that there is no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the ngModel doesn't give any values to the input because the id properties of the two objects are the same!

If I change from this:

```
myList: any;
outlets: any;
ngOnInit(){
    this.myList = [
        {id: 1, name: 'a'},
        {id: 2, name: 'b'},
        {id: 3, name: 'c'},
        {id: 4, name: 'd'},
    ];
    this.outlets = [
        {id: 1, name: 'a'},
        {id: 2, name: 'b'},
        {id: 3, name: 'c'},
        {id: 4, name: 'd'},
    ];
}
```

To this:

```
myList: any;
outlets: any;
ngOnInit(){
    this.myList = [
        {id: 1, name: 'a'},
        {id: 2, name: 'b'},
        {id: 3, name: 'c'},
        {id: 4, name: 'd'},
    ];
    this.outlets = [
        {id: 5, name: 'a'},
        {id: 6, name: 'b'},
        {id: 7, name: 'c'},
        {id: 8, name: 'd'},
    ];
}
```

Then it works! ask me why? I don't know.. If someone can explain would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You should change your template. There is no `name` attribute on your returned data:

```
<input *ngFor="let l of myList" [(ngModel)]="l.outletName" name="{{l.id}}" />
```

Ohh, well.. Gunter already mentioned this in his comment :)

Comment: No no, i want from the name property from this.myList, not outletName from this.outlets

Comment: Actually, I mocked the data this.myList, I actually have to called another service to render in my input, but I just mocked it first to see if it's working.